# MultipartFile resource cannot be resolved using mockMvk.perform

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am using spring boot and to try my request using IT tests I use mockMvc.

I am creating a MultipartFile using MockMultipartFile :

```
String imagePath = new ClassPathResource("images/jkrowling.jpg").getPath();
    Path path = Paths.get("src/it/resources/" + imagePath);
    MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("jkrowling.jpg", "jkrowling.jpg", "image/jpeg", Files.readAllBytes(path));
```

And this works. I am also creating a FileRequest which is my own class who got only one property: a MultipartFile:

```
FileRequest fileRequest = FileRequest.builder()
            .file(multipartFile)
            .build();
```

from the class:

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.extern.jackson.Jacksonized;
@Getter
@Builder
@Jacksonized
@ToString
public class FileRequest {
    @NotBlank(message = "L'image de l'auteur est obligatoire.")
    private final MultipartFile file;
}
```

After logging my FileRequest.getFile() this is what I have:

```
MultipartFileResource@82 "MultipartFile resource [jkrowling.jpg]"
multipartFile:MockMultipartFile@72
content:byte[7799]@87
contentType:"image/jpeg"
name:"jkrowling.jpg"
originalFilename:"jkrowling.jpg"
```

I am doing this (this is where the error appear):

```
mockMvc.perform(new QueryRequestBuilder(jkRowlingId, fileRequest).build())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

with

```
private static class QueryRequestBuilder extends AbstractRequestBuilder {

        private final String authorId;

        private QueryRequestBuilder(String authorId, FileRequest fileRequest) throws Exception {
            this.authorId = authorId;
            content(fileRequest);
            method(HttpMethod.POST);
        }
        
        @Override
        protected String computeUrl() {
            return String.format("%s/%s/%s", AUTHORS_PREFIX, "file", this.authorId);
        }
    }
```

But I got the following error:
`Unexpected IOException (of type java.io.FileNotFoundException): MultipartFile resource [jkrowling.jpg] cannot be resolved to absolute file path`

Hope someone already got this issue.

Comment: You are making things to complex. You already have a resource us `getInputStream` and the Spring `StreamUtils` to read the inputstream into a byte[]. Ditch the path and file stuff. As it isn't a file but a resource in your classpath ( a `java.util.File` needs to be a resource on your file system, this isn't).

Comment: @M.Deinum The problem is not the file itself because it is a valid one when I passed it to my QueryBuilder

Comment: In the end that is your problem, also why a custom request builder seems consulted to me.

Comment: InputStream imagePath = new ClassPathResource("images/jkrowling.jpg").getInputStream();
MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("jkrowling.jpg", "jkrowling.jpg", "image/jpeg", StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(imagePath));

this is what I should do ? @M.Deinum

Comment: Well I would just use `new MockMulitpartFile("jkrowling.jpg", imagePath)` and leave everything else be. Keep it simple.